# Checking if an element has one class vs another alway returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if an element has one of two classes. If it doesn't then it should run some other function. I'm using the `||` or operator but, regardless of the if statement, it always returns true and runs the inner functionality, which is not what I expect. Is my syntax wrong here?

```
if (!elm.hasClass('report-error') || !elm.hasClass('data-error')) {
     // Do something 
}
```

Comment: So the only time that condition will be false (won't execute) is when the element has both classes. Is that what you're after?

Comment: No, I intend for it to be false if it has one or the other. It wont ever have both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition will be true when the element does not have both classes, which includes the scenarios where the element has neither class or only one of the classes.  It will only become false when the element has both classes.

You currently have the condition (!A OR !B), which his logically equivalent to !(A AND B).

It sounds like you want it to be true when the element has neither of the two classes.  In that case, what you want is !(A OR B), which can also be written as (!A AND !B).

Both of these statements will do what you want:

```
// !(A OR B)
if (!(elm.hasClass('report-error') || elm.hasClass('data-error'))) {
    // Has neither class, so do something else
}
```

or this:

```
// !A AND !B
if (!elm.hasClass('report-error') && !elm.hasClass('data-error')) {
    // Has neither class, so do something else
}
```

---

You could also keep it super simple (and more readable) by checking if it has one class or the other, and handling the "neither" case in the the ELSE statement:

```
if (elm.hasClass('report-error') || elm.hasClass('data-error')) {
    // Has one class or the other
} else {
    // Has neither class, so do something else
}
```

Comment: and to get rid of the else statement you can always negotiate the statement `if ( cond || cond2 ) {} else {` === `if ( !(cond || cond2) ) {`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a logical error - does not have X or does not have Y. This will be true in most cases.

```
if (!(elm.hasClass('report-error') || elm.hasClass('data-error'))) {
 // Do something 
}
```

That will check if any of the classes are there, then invert it (so not there).